# Bind my form to a Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ViewModel which contains a List of my Model, like so:

```
public class OrderConfirm
{
    public ICollection<DayBookQuoteLines> SalesLines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DayBookQuoteLines> LostLines { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

I then use this ViewModel in my View like so:

```
@model btn_intranet.Areas.DayBook.Models.ViewModels.OrderConfirm
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Daybook - Order Confirmation";
}

<h6>Sales Lines</h6>
<div id="SalesOrders">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ConfirmSalesOrder", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "SalesOrders",
    OnBegin = "SalesOrderConfirm"
}))
{
    @foreach(var item in Model.SalesLines)
    {
        <p>@item.ItemName</p>
        <p>@item.Qty</p>

        @* Other Properties *@
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Sales Order" />
}
</div>

<h6>Lost Lines</h6>
<div id="LostOrders">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ConfirmLostOrder", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "LostOrders",
    OnBegin = "LostOrderConfirm"
}))
{
    @foreach(var item in Model.SalesLines)
    {
        <p>@item.ItemName</p>
        <p>@item.Qty</p>

        @* Other Properties *@
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Lost Order" />
}
</div>
```

The problem is, in my `[HttpPost]` actions, both `ConfirmSalesOrder` and `ConfirmLostOrder`. The value of my Model passed as a parameter is null:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmSalesOrder(List<DayBookQuoteLines> quoteLines)
{

    // Process order...

    return PartialView("Sales/_ConfirmSalesOrder");
}
```

so `quoteLines` is null. How can I bind the form to my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any input field in your form that will send the values to the server. You are only displaying them. That's why they are null when you submit the form => nothing is sent to the server.

But if inside this form the user is not supposed to modify any of the values all you need to do is to pass an id to the controller action that will allow you to fetch the model from the exact same location from which you fetched it in your GET action that rendered this form.

In this case your action will look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmSalesOrder(int id)
{
    List<DayBookQuoteLines> quoteLines = ... fetch them the same way as in your GET action
    // Process order...

    return PartialView("Sales/_ConfirmSalesOrder");
}
```

If on the other hand the user is supposed to modify the values in the form you need to provide him with the necessary input fields: things like textboxes, checkboxes, radio buttons, dropdownlists, textereas, ... And in order to generate proper names for those input fields I would recommend you using editor templates instead of writing foreach loops in your views.

---

UPDATE:

Seems like the user is not supposed to edit the data so there are no corresponding input fields. In this case in order to preserve the model you could during the AJAX request you could replace the `Ajax.BeginForm` with a normal `Html.BeginForm` an then manually wire up the AJAX request with jQuery. The advantage of this approach is that now you have far more control and you could for example send the entire model as a JSON request. To do this you could store the model as a javascript encoded variable inside the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

and then AJAXify the form:

```
$('#formId').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ quoteLines: model }),
        success: function(result) {
            $('#someTargetIdToUpdate').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The problem is, the way I fetched them in the GET request was to hold them in TempData as I havent actually committed any changes to the database yet as the View is a sort of Confirmation Page, which will then commit the changes to the database once they click on submit

Comment: In this case you will have to provide hidden fields for each property that you want to persist. The best way is to do this throughout an editor template to ensure that proper names are generated for those hidden fields. There are no miracles. The HTTP protocol is stateless in its nature. Someone might also suggest you using the Session instead of TempData. Personally I wouldn't use it nor recommend it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another technique that you could use. It consists in serializing the model into a javascript variable that you could repass to the controller action when sending the AJAX request.